# How to get rid of scroll bar in Blogspot?

Tags: blogger

I just started using [Blogspot](http://adhikarisubir.blogspot.in/). I don't know much about handling it. Now the problem I am facing is that I am getting an unnecessary scroll bar in the right hand side of some of my posts. How can I remove it? Here is the picture:

[image]

In the main page also, I am facing the same problem.

[image]

I tried adjusting the widths from the templates but it could not help.

Comment: it might be the height you want to alter.

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem solved. The problem was due to the fact that I first wrote in another online editor where the scroll bar came and from there I copy-pasted into the blogger editor. So the scroll bar also got pasted.

Then to solve the problem I first copy-pasted into MS Word and from there I copy-pasted into the Blogger editor and the problem got solved.